# Listing mime-type for each input file

Tags: bash, scripting, mime-types

I want to pass a set of file names to a bash function, and list the mime-type as follows.

```
video/mp4  file.mp4
video/mkv  file.mkv
```

Here is the loop iterating each file

```
  for fl in "$@"; do
   if [[ -f "$fl" ]]; then
     if file --mime-type -b "$fl"
     then
       printf '"%s" \n' "$fl"
     fi
   fi
  done
```

Comment: What is your question?

Comment: by the way, never ever trust `file` on files from untrusted third parties. As a [humorous example](http://catless.ncl.ac.uk/Risks/25/77#subj14.1), here's what goes wrong if you use `file` to detect the type of printed document, instead of explicitly passing the type information through the print system (which would have been architecturally trivial to do from libreoffice to printer driver, but it's not how printing systems were designed). On a less humorous note, it's pretty trivial to trick `file` into believing something is an MKV file (first 8 bytes or so), but some (many) decoders will try

Comment: to find a new stream further down in the file if the decoding of the first stream fails (that's one way to get so-called *polyglotts*, files that can be multiple file times at once). Now, maybe you're doing something based on the file type you detected – omitting some transcoding options that are known to be buggy for one format, for example – and someone can trick you into treating the file as if it was "safe", where it really wasn't.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use command substitution:

```bash
for fl in "$@"; do
   if [[ -f "$fl" ]]; then
       printf '%s\t%s\n' "$(file --mime-type -b "$fl")" "$fl"
   fi
done
```